# Wifi Direct peers connection in android

Tags: java, android, p2p, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I am developing an application in which it will search for the nearby peers and it will send connection request to all of them one by one it will act as a group owner, Is there a way to know if the some peer is busy or not at some moment?? so I send connection request to only idle peers.

Comment: What do you mean by "busy"?

Comment: This is the same question as one you asked 9 days before. If you want to revise a question, please edit it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112843